# Recursively traverse a tree with a string

Tags: c, string, pointers, recursion

I'm trying to recursively traverse a tree and carry a string through the recursion.

The idea is (for huffman coding), starting at the root, if you go left, concatenate a 0 to your string, if you go right, concatenate a 1. When you get to a leaf, your final string is a string of 0s and 1s that is your "encoding".

Here is my function:

```
void encode_tree(bin_node *root, char *string)
{
if(root->left==NULL && root->right==NULL)
{
    root->encoding = string;
    printf("%d got an encoding of %s\n", root->data, root->encoding);
    return;
}

root->encoding = string;
encode_tree(root->left, strcat(string, "0"));
encode_tree(root->right, strcat(string, "1"));
}
```

But this code is wrong, it gives me incorrect encodings.

Let's say I have this tree:

```
            3\65

        6\-1

            3\70

    9\-1

            2\66

        3\-1

            1\67
16\-1

    7\68
```

My encoding for 7/86 should be 0, 1/67 should be 100, 2/66 should be 101, and 3/70 should be 110 and 3/65 should be 111.

But here are the encodings I get from my function:

```
 7/68 got an encoding of 0
 1/67 got an encoding of 0100
 2/66 got an encoding of 01001
 3/70 got an encoding of 0100110
 3/65 got an encoding of 01001101
```

Comment: It has admittedly been awhile since i've done huffman trees, but from what I recall each node should have at-most a *char* (or at most an index into a buffer) and then only if it is a leaf; not an entire string. so... wtf?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that you have **only one unique string allocated**, and you are trying to give each element its own unique encoding. This cannot work, because by the end of it, **they are ALL referring to the SAME string**.

You need to use `strdup` or allocate a new string and copy over from `string` every time you want to assign it to a `bin_node::encoding`

Change

```
root->encoding = string;
```

to 
    SetEncoding(root, string);

where

```
void SetEncoding(bin_node* n, char* e)
{
    char *d = malloc (strlen (e) + 1);   // Space for length plus nul
    if (d == NULL) return NULL;          // No memory
    strcpy (d,s);                        // Copy the characters
    n->encoding = d; 
}
```

Comment: YES! You were exactly correct. Adding strdup(string) to the recursive call instead of just string fixed it! Thanks!

Comment: @Josh glad to have been of help, please feel free to mark as answer if this answers your question satisfactorily.

Answer (score 0):

strcat has the effect of appending characters onto the end of the string, but where is the code that removes characters from the end? Note how in the example below, the '1' value replaces the '0' value. This is not true of your code; Your code appends the '0', then appends the '1' after the '0'.

```
// usage: encode_tree(root, string, string);
void encode_tree(bin_node *root, char *string, char *end)
{
    if(root->left==NULL && root->right==NULL)
    {
        *end = '\0';
        printf("%d got an encoding of %s\n", root->data, root->encoding);
        return;
    }

    root->encoding = string;
    *end = '0'; encode_tree(root->left, string, end + 1);
    *end = '1'; encode_tree(root->right, string, end + 1);
```

}